# React-Image-Annotate - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use [react-image-annotate](https://github.com/UniversalDataTool/react-image-annotate) but it's giving me this issue when I first try to set it up.

[image]

And here's how I'm using it:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactImageAnnotate from 'react-image-annotate'

function ImageAnnotator() {
    return (
        <ReactImageAnnotate
            selectedImage="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561518776-e76a5e48f731?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"
            // taskDescription="# Draw region around each face\n\nInclude chin and hair."
            // images={[
            //     { src: 'https://example.com/image1.png', name: 'Image 1' },
            // ]}
            // regionClsList={['Man Face', 'Woman Face']}
        />
    )
}

export default ImageAnnotator
```

I'm using Next.js if that matters

**UPDATE 1**
I tried using this [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs) as suggested by Alejandro Vales. It gives the same error as before. Here's the `babel` key in my `package.json`:

```
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "next/babel"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            [
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
                {
                    "legacy": true
                }
            ],
            [
                "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
                {
                    "allowTopLevelThis": true
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Comment: If you’re using next.js, you’ll have to add your Babel webpack stuff in next.config.js I believe.

Comment: Hmm that is what the docs say. I remember there was a reason I added the `babel` key to `package.json` instead of `next.config.js` but I can't quite remember. I'll look into it and update here.

Comment: So according to [babel's docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#file-relative-configuration), you can add the `babel` key in `package.json`. This should apply for Next.js as well because the other plugin fixed a separate issue I was having.

Comment: Look at https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the issue relies in the library itself by what they replied in here (similar bug) https://github.com/UniversalDataTool/react-image-annotate/issues/90#issuecomment-683221311

Indeed *one way to fix it* I would say is adding babel to the project so you can transform the `imports` in your project to `require` automatically without having to change the code on your whole project.

This is the babel package you are looking for https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs

Another reason for this could be an outdated version of your package, as some people report to have this fixed after using a newer version of `Create React App` (https://github.com/UniversalDataTool/react-image-annotate/issues/37#issuecomment-607372287)

*Another fix you could do* (a little crazier depending on your resources) is forking the library, creating a CJS version of the lib, and then pushing that to the library, so you and anybody else can use that in the future.

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I tried Next.js's dynamic imports, which didn't work. I also tried the babel plugin you shared, however it gives the same error. Perhaps I didn't use it properly? See Update 1 in the body of the post for my package.json

Answer (score 1):

I got a tricky solution!

Problem is that react-image-annotate can only be imported in client-side(SSR got error for import keyword)

So, let react-image-annotate in Nextjs be imported only in client side
(https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

in Next Page that needs this component, You can make component like this

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("src/components/Upload/Annotation"), { ssr: false });
import { NextPage } from "next";

const Page: NextPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
             <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
        </>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

Make component like this

```
//@ts-ignore
import ReactImageAnnotate from "react-image-annotate";
import React from "react";

const Annotation = () => {
    return (
        <ReactImageAnnotate
            labelImages
            regionClsList={["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta"]}
            regionTagList={["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]}
            images={[
                {
                    src: "https://placekitten.com/408/287",
                    name: "Image 1",
                    regions: [],
                },
            ]}
        />
    );
};

export default Annotation;
```